# How is a group of deliverables called?

Tags: work-breakdown-structure, terminology

They are not projects, as one project contains more groups of deliverables. Is milestone a correct term?

I hope the chart below explains it a little.
[image]

Comment: WBS has levels. Between the top level and the "deliverables" there could be multiple levels, so each of those levels should have a name. If you search for a general term for items in levels, consider "scope elements".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bartosz writes in the comments, there can be multiple levels between the top and the lowest level of your WBS, and the number of levels of each sub-tree depends upon the deliverable itself.

Now, the first level often depends upon how you wish to structure your WBS: it could be by project phase (if each phase has distinct deliverables) or by product. We often use the release number, if the project contains multiple releases, besides the other main deliverables. This makes it easier for the customer to see what they will get in each release.

We just call the first level the **"main" or "major" deliverables**, and it is broken down into sub-deliverables. The lowest level are called "Work packages", as normally you don't break them down any further but define the tasks needed to realise them. Tasks belong in your schedule, however. I prefer to keep the WBS free of tasks, so as to make it **deliverable-focused**.

So my first level would read "website" or "planning board", and it would be broken down from there up till the level that I wish to manage.

A milestone is part of a schedule, and indicates that a deliverable is completed at a certain date like "Website released" or something like that.

Comment: I am a little confused on what you mean by deliverable-focused. Is that the same thing as a product breakdown?

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

1. Hammock
2. Control Account
3. Parent Deliverable / Activity
4. Sub-project
5. Group of deliverables

Comment: David, Do you define Control Accounts always on the first level of the WBS? We assign them further down as well. It depends upon the level of detail you or your SteerCo/Sponsor wish to manage.

Comment: I define a control account based on the size of the $$ and staffing (same thing, really).  At that level of the WBS, I want a single leader on it, which means the span of control needs to be appropriate.  So it can be anywhere in a multi-level WBS, just at that level where span of control is just right, e.g., 10 to 15 resources??

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to view your chart, but how about calling the group either a phase, stage or a work package?